# Changing label text property periodically

Tags: c#

I have a label. I need to change the text property every 3 seconds. Please let me know how to do this. I tried using timer, but my application is going into infinite loop. I do not want this to happen/ Any help will be appreciated!

```
timer1.Interval = 5000; 
timer1.Enabled = true; 
timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler (OnTimerEvent);

private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    refreshStatusBar();
}
```

Comment: Please post the code you have. There may be something fairly straightforward that you've missed

Comment: Show us the code you're using please.

Comment: What do you mean by "but my application is going into infinite loop"? Also, you should post your code.

Comment: I have out the following in page load: timer1.Interval = 5000; timer1.Enabled = true; timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler (OnTimerEvent); This is the ontimedevent: private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e) { refreshStatusBar(); } By infinite loop i mean that whenever I am right clicking on the page, or clicking any buttons, it is not responding

Comment: Edit your question, don't post comments. Show us `OnTimerEvent` code please

Comment: Please, SHOW US YOUR CODE!! `refreshStatusBar()` means nothing, what does this procedure do?

Comment: private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {

            refreshStatusBar();

        }
refreshStatusBar is the function I want to call periodically

Comment: If this method does nothing, how can your app go into an infinite loop?

Comment: The `timer.Internal` is in milliseconds, i.e. 5000 is 5 seconds. In the problem description you say you want to change the text every 3 seconds which would require you to set `time.Interval` to 3000.

Comment: Can you show the code **where timer1 is instantiated**?

Answer (score 0):

In your class constructor, you need to initialize the initial text for the `Label` and the .NET Framework's  `Timer` component.

```
timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
timer.Interval = (1000) * (3); // Timer will tick every 3 seconds
timer.Enabled = true;
timer.Start();

label.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString(); // initial label text.
```

Then in the timer's tick handler, update the `Label`'s text property.

```
private void timer_Tick(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
        label.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString(); // update text ...
}
```

Comment: When using the above code, my application is going into infinite loop. Whenever I right click on the page, or click on any button, it stops responding. :(

Comment: I suggest the problem is with your handler -- edit your question to include that code.

Comment: @bhavna: are you sure your application is not performing any other action?

Answer (score -1):

You should use thread, and when you want to stop call yourthread.Abort();

**Update:** SynchronizationContext method:

```
System.Threading.SynchronizationContext sync;
private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    sync = SynchronizationContext.Current;
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer tm = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer { Interval = 1000 };
    tm.Tick += tm_Tick;
    tm.Start();
}

//Handles tm.Tick
private void tm_Tick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    sync.Post(dopost, DateAndTime.Now.ToString());
}

public void dopost(string txt)
{
    Label1.Text = txt;
}
```

Comment: When using threads, I ma getting an error if I am trying to modify the UI controls from the thread. The error is as follows:    Cross-thread operation not valid: Control accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on

Comment: @bhavna: you should use `Invoke(...)`

Comment: or use SynchronizationContext

Comment: How can I alter UI Control properties from another thread? I tried doing that initially, but it gave me an error 
 Cross-thread operation not valid: Control accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on

Comment: @bhavna: do you read other responses? I've already told you you should use `Inovke(..)`